# nUnit: Test Explorer не показывает тесты

Tags: юнит-тесты, visual-studio-2015, nunit

Добрый день. Имеется Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 3.

Установлены через NuGet nUnit 2.6.4 и nUnitTestAdapter 2.0.

При запуске юнит-теста, в окне Вывод, вкладка Тесты, видно, что тесты находятся и запускаются. По командам выполнить неудачные тесты и выполнить пройденные тесты даже можно понять, прошли тесты, или нет. Т.е., если тест прошёл, при запуске неудачных тестов в консоли появляется сообщение Нет тестов для запуска и т.д.

Однако при этом Test Explorer не показывает вообще ничего.

Comment: Убедитесь, что архитектура проекта с тестами совпадает с архитектурой, указанной в настройках Студии: Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture.

Comment: да, везде одинаково x64

Comment: Попробуйте тогда решения отсюда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560011/visual-studio-2015-does-not-discover-unit-tests.

Comment: пока что не работает

Comment: вопрос решился установкой английской версии Visual Studio (была русская)

Comment: Это странно. Язык не должен влиять. Может другая версия, апдейт?

Comment: не увидел разницы, тоже Update 3